# How to solve this differential equation with two variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The answer of the second-order differential equation $\lambda''(t)+a^2\lambda (t)=0$ (with $a$ constant) is $\lambda (t)=A\sin (at)+B\cos (at)$. But what is the answer of equation $\lambda'' (t,x)+a^2 \lambda (t,x)=0$ in which $\lambda'(x,t)=\frac{d\lambda (x,t)}{dt}$?

Comment: the same I think, but with $A$ and $B$ as functions of $x$

Comment: Simply $\lambda (t)=A(x)\sin (at)+B(x)\cos (at)$

Comment: @Aryadeva But $\lambda (x,t)=\frac{1}{a}\sin a(t-x)$ is also an answer of above equation. Why?

Comment: Do you know what a partial differential equation is?

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes, I know.

Comment: For $\lambda (x,t)=\frac{1}{a}\sin a(t-x)$ Use addition formula on the sine function and see what you get Ramana

Comment: @Aryadeva Sure. I'll do it. Thanks a lot for the comment.

Comment: You're welcome Ramana. Then look at the formula I posted and see if your solution is not included on that formula. Ramana

Comment: @Aryadeva Could you please explain more about solving the equation to get the answer $\lambda (x,t)=\frac{1}{a}\sin a(t-x)$?

Comment: @Aryadeva I've taken $\lambda (x,t)=A\sin(f(x,t))+B\cos(g(x,t))$, but I can't solve it.

Comment: Ok will add more lines in an answer...Ramana

Comment: +1 for all your efforts.

Comment: @Aryadeva I'm grateful for your kindness. I've got $f(x)=\frac{1}{a}\cos(ax)$ and $g(x)=-\frac{1}{a}\sin(ax)$ from conditions, and hence $\lambda (t,x)=\frac{1}{a}\sin(a(t-x))$ as a spectial answer. Thank you a lot for your guidance.

Comment: oh Thats great if you finally got the correct answer. You're welcome. Ramana

Comment: @Aryadeva Yes. I got the answer thanks to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*But what is the answer of equation*
$$\lambda'' (t,x)+a^2 \lambda (t,x)=0$$
It's simply:
$$\lambda (x,t)=A(x)\sin (at)+B(x)\cos (at)$$

---

For your question in the comments:

$$\lambda (x,t)=\frac{1}{a}\sin a(t-x)$$
Note that:
$$\sin (at-ax)=\sin (at)\cos(ax)-\cos(at)\sin(ax)$$
So that:
$$\lambda (x,t)=\frac{1}a (\sin (at)\cos(ax)-\cos(at)\sin(ax))$$
This is on the form:
$$\lambda (x,t)=f(x)\sin (at)+g(x)\cos(at)$$
This is just:
$$\lambda (x,t)=A(x)\sin (at)+B(x)\cos (at)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and consideration. I understood completely. Now, as you said, I consider $\lambda (x,t)=f(x)\sin (at)+g(x)\cos (at)$. For the last question, for the conditions $\lambda (x,x)=0$ and $\lambda'(x,x)=1$, is it enough to take derivative from $\lambda (x,t)=f(x)\sin (at)+g(x)\cos (at)$ with respect to $t$ to get the answer $\frac{1}{a}\sin a(t-x)$?

Comment: if the $\lambda '$ is taken acording to the variable $t$ yes differentiate with respect to $t$ the general solution ...@M.Ramana

Comment: OK. Understood it properly. Thank you very much for your help. I'm so sorry to ask a lot of questions. Thanks.

Comment: No problem we are here to ask and answer questions. You are very welcome @M.Ramana

Comment: Thank you for your favor.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example $\lambda(t,x) = A\sin (at+x)+B\cos (at+x)$. Then $\partial_t\lambda = aA\cos (at+x)-aB\sin (at+x)$ and $\partial_{tt}^2\lambda = -a^2A\sin(at+x)-a^2B\cos (at+x)$. In this case $\lambda$ satisfies the equation
$$\partial_{tt}^2\lambda(t,x)+a^2\lambda(t,x)=0.$$
But then it is simple to check that any $$\lambda(t,x) = A\sin(at+f(x))+B\cos (at+g(x))$$ satisfies the same equation for $f,g$ functions of $x$.

In case $a=0$ then you have particular solutions, because $\lambda$ satisfies $\partial_{tt}^2\lambda(t,x)=0$. This implies
$\partial_t\lambda(t,x) = f(x)$ and $\lambda(t,x)=tf(x)+g(x)$ for some functions $f,g$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Where do you take $\lambda (x,t)$ from that way? How can I understand to take $\lambda (x,t)$ as $A\sin(at+x)+B\cos(at+x)$?

Comment: I was just trying to do some inspection. The simplest thing was to add an $x$ somewhere in your solution. Try to modify my first example putting the $x$ somewhere else.

Comment: OK. I'll do it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is there a general method to solve these kinds of equations? I didn't understand how to solve it without considering a first guess.